# Can sqlite and MySQL access the same database?

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, sqlite

I'm developing a web application. It's divided into two parts.

Part 1 is content generation. This entails downloading databases in diverse formats, converting the relevant content to a unified form, doing some processing on it, and placing it in a single integrated database. I've been using Python + sqlite3 for this.

Part 2 is the client/server application. This entails accessing the unified database created in Part 1, and reading and updating it depending on the user's behavior. My plan was to use JavaScript + Node + MySQL for this. I'm learning this part as I go.

Even after the initial content is loaded into the database, I'll periodically need to add more. Ideally this would happen using the same Python/Sqlite3 app, without interruption to the client/server application.

I understand that sqlite3 and MySQL use a different architecture. I'm not sure if they can access the same database, or whether this is a reasonable architecture for this program. I could rewrite the Python + sqlite3 part in Javascript + MySQL so that the whole application is in one unified language, but I don't want to if possible since I've already developed a lot of code.

Is this two-language model appropriate for this kind of application? Can you point me to any tutorials on how to interface between sqlite and MySQL?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and switch to a single database arch if possible. Any solution you come up with WILL have downfalls, be messy, or will not live up to expectations.

Comment: The problem is not with the two language, but with the two databases. It will take you FAR less time to change the Python code so that it uses the same MySQL server as the JS code, than to try and use two different databases.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll swap out the sqlite for MySQL and keep the rest.